# Не работает StyledProperty в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalonia, ef

У меня есть userControl Карусели фотографий, взятой из каталога примеров реализации некоторых контролов(https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/samples/ControlCatalog/Pages/CarouselPage.xaml)

Я его благополучно внедрил в проект, и далее мне необходимо, чтобы фотографии для карусели подгружались из массива данных. Для этого я сделал StyledProperty, так как вместо DependencyProperty на официальном сайте авалонии просят использовать именно StyledProperty(https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/get-started/wpf/dependencyproperty)

```
public static readonly StyledProperty<IEnumerable > ItemSourseProperty = AvaloniaProperty.Register<CarouselPage, IEnumerable >(
        nameof(ItemSourcePr));

    public IEnumerable  ItemSourcePr
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemSourseProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSourseProperty, value);
    }
```

Далее в UserControl выставляю это свойство на ItemSource карусели:

```
<Carousel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=CoureselControl}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourcePr}" Grid.Row="1" Name="carousel">
```

B основное окно подключаю карусель, указав созданное свойство:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
     <control:CarouselPage ItemSourcePr="{Binding MainImageCollection}"></control:CarouselPage>
</StackPanel>
```

И получаю такую ошибку:
**CarouselPage.axaml(26, 69): [AVLN:0004] Unable to resolve property or method of name 'ItemSourcePr' on type 'AvaloniaScantrak.ViewModels.MainViewModel'. Line 26, position 69.**

Пробовал включать CompiledBinding, но это не помогло

Comment: `<UserControl x:Name="uc" ...>` далее привязку переделываете на такой вид `{Binding ItemSourcePr, ElementName=uc}`.

Comment: Благодарю, старая ошибка исчезла, теперь появилась новая:
  MainWindow.axaml(147, 43): [AVLN:0004] Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property ItemSourcePr of type AvaloniaScantrak:AvaloniaScantrak.Controls.CarouselPage for argument Avalonia.Markup.Xaml:Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.CompiledBindingExtension, available setter parameter lists are:
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Object Line

Я так понимаю, нужно поменять тип свойства на нечто иное.

Comment: MainImageCollection имеет тип ObservableCollection<Image>

Comment: Тут уже не ко мне вопрос, это причуды авалонии которую я не особо долюбливаю))